# Wen i try to import any thing like an icon to visual basic 2012 the window dont pop up

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I try to import any thing like an icon to visual basic 2012 the window dialogbox what normally pop up don t pop up anymore.

I try to restart the computer and nothing change.
any way to solve this issue?
here it is the print https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp4e6.jpg i have pressed the button to browse and nothing happen.
My question is there is anyway to solve this issue how to get it back work like before?

Answer (score -1):

Well i did not find any solution for it i have try to reinstall and nothing i presume its from my computer so i reinstalled the windows operation system and make a backup from my registry
install visual studio 
and make a backup of the registry like that i am sure it will be the same i hope.